# In Hive what is the difference between FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0004' and FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u001C'

Tags: hive, hiveql

In my project I saw two Hive tables and in the create table statement I saw one table has ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0004'   and another table has ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u001C'. I want to know what does these '\u0004' and '\u001C' mean and when to use them? Kindly answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

In many text formats, `\u` introduces a Unicode escape sequence. This is a way of storing or sending a character that can't be easily displayed or represented in the format you're using. The four characters after the `\u` are the Unicode "code point" in hexadecimal. A Unicode code point is a number denoting a specific Unicode character.

All characters have a code point, even the printable ones. For example, `a` is [`U+0061`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0061).

[`U+0004`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0004) and [`U+001C`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+001C) are both unprintable characters, meaning there's no standard character you can use to display them on the screen. That's why an escape sequence is used here.

If you use a simple, printable character like `,` as your field delimiter, it will make the stored data easier for a human to read. The field values will be stored with a `,` between each one. For example, you might see the values `one`, `two` and `three` stored as:

```
one,two,three
```

But if you expect your field values to actually *contain* a `,`, it would be a poor choice of field delimiter (because then you'd need a special way to tell the difference between a single field with a value of `one,two` or two different fields with the values `one` and `two`). The choice of delimiter depends both on whether you want to be able to read it easily, and what characters you expect the field to contain.

Comment: So, will these two  '\u0004' or '\u001C' show the same result in the dataset and no difference as a delimiter while creating Hive Table ?